# python error run script list index out of range

Tags: python

i've found one python script here: `https://github.com/vertuzz/spotyloader`

csv to try here: `https://www.upload.ee/files/12600304/98469854.csv.html`

installed ok `requirements.txt` --- `npm install` installed .msi pakage on my system.

problem is the script `run.py`: when run for each file have `list index out of range`
how to solve this problem? i've publish my issue to developer on github but him it's missing...
tanxs for your help.

Comment: you’re not at the right place here: you have to give the smallest complete code that reproduces the error, or precise error messages. Otherwise, nobody can help you.

Comment: ok tanxs for your suggestion!

Answer (score 1):

this is an example: `python run.py D:\newfolder D:\000`
on `D:\newfolder` i've put my csv file
when run my script `python run.py D:\newfolder D:\000`
i have for each track this error:

```
D:\Python-3.8.1 x64>python run.py D:\newfolder D:\000
Levitating spotify:artist:6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we, spotify:artist:
4r63FhuTkUYltbVAg5TQnk
list index out of range
Failed Levitating spotify:artist:6M2wZ9GZgrQXHCFfjv46we, spotify:
artist:4r63FhuTkUYltbVAg5TQnk
```